# Getting Max count based on Vehid group by Houseid Django

Tags: django, count, max, aggregate, annotate

[This is the image of the table and output required with details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6wnN.png)

So, I wrote a Django query

ModelClassName.objects.values('houseid','vehid').annotate(Count('vehid')).order_by('houseid')

This is giving me the count of each vehid but as I am not sure how to incorporate Max here, I am unable to get the right result. 
Any help is appreciable. 
Thanks.

Comment: With the current code, what are you getting as output? Can you past the queryset here?

Comment: This is not from the example I have written but this is the actual Queryset that I get <QuerySet [{'vehid__count': 13, 'vehid': '02', 'houseid': '20000017'}, {'vehid__count': 5, 'vehid': '01', 'houseid': '20000231'}, {'vehid__count': 4, 'vehid': '01', 'houseid': '20000521'}, {'vehid__count': 2, 'vehid': '02', 'houseid': '20000521'}, {'vehid__count': 4, 'vehid': '-1', 'houseid': '20001283'}, {'vehid__count': 2, 'vehid': '01', 'houseid': '20001603'}, {'vehid__count': 7, 'vehid': '03', 'houseid': '20001603'}]>

Comment: I am not seeing a solution with annotate itself, may I suggest some SQL alternative? Or a logic for this queryset?

Comment: Sure that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view to get the counts:

```
SELECT HOUSEID, VEHID, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE GROUP BY HOUSEID, VEHID
```

Then query the View

```
Select Houseid, VEHID, COUNT from MYVIEW A where A.COUNT = (Select Max(B.count) FROM MYVIEW B WHERE A.HOUSEID = B.HOUSEID)
```

Then you can use Django SQL (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/) to help you.

(test and let me know if that worked)